# Laravel Ajax response returning text above json

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.5

I'm writing to my model using ajax and if there is an error like a duplicate I need it to throw a json response.

```
$model = Product::find($id);
$model->{$col} = $request->value;    

try{
        $model->save();
    } catch (Exception $e){   
        return Response::json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
```

If there is an error it returns the following with a response code of 200 so my error handling in ajax doesn't get to touch this. I also can't handle it in the success function because it's not pure json

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Mon, 22 Jan 2018 16:06:17 GMT

{"error":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...."}
```

I found adding `http_response_code(500)` Before the return did then give me a status response of 500 but the responseText was still the same and contained the extra text and not just pure json

The response I want should look this

```
{"error":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...."}
```

Here's my js ajax code

```
var post_data = {id:$(this.attr('id),value:$(this).value()}   



$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data: post_data,
    beforeSend:function(){
       //stuff here to show user somethign is happening
    },
    success:function(returned_data){

        console.log('successful!')

        console.log(returned_data);
    },
    error:function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError ) {
         console.log('event');
         console.log(event);
         console.log('jqXHR');
         console.log(jqXHR.responseText);

         console.log('thrownError');
         console.log(thrownError);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong that laravel is sending this text that looks like the headers, instead of just the pure json?

Edit: Added code before try catch

Also, I am purposefully causing this error so I can make sure my error handling is working but isn't because I'm not getting pure json and it's returning a 200 response code

Comment: What is above ----> `try{
    $model->save();`  ? And what `post_data` contains ?

Comment: Added the code above `try catch` and `post data`. I'm purposefully causing the error to check my error handling works

Comment: im not sure if this one helps but you might want to try using this format `return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'last_insert_id' => $data->id), 200);` in returning your data?

Comment: Still returns text above the json array `HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Mon, 22 Jan 2018 18:50:13 GMT

{"status":true}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after lots of testing I found the problem. With my ajax data that I send back to the server, I send a function name with that calls the function to use. The problem was that I was using `echo` for pushing the data back.

```
echo $_POST['ajax_function_name']();
```

Changing the `echo` to `return` will now return the correct json response when using  `Response::json();`

The reason behind this happening was moving functions from a legacy app to the new laravel app and overlooked this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your `App\Exceptions\Handler`